# g++ not finding header files during compilation despite headers existing in include path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, sfml, include-path

I'm trying to run the SFML example found at the bottom of the page [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/index.php) using VSCode and g++.

Before compilation, the SFML include file `C:\GL\SFML-master\include` is in the C++ Configurations include path. VSCode throws errors if I change this, so I don't believe it's the problem.

However, when I run/debug the file, g++ throws `fatal error: SFML/Audio.hpp: No such file or directory`

I've tried playing around with the file location and path but I'm not quite sure what is actually going wrong.

The only code in my program is the example above, and the only changes I've made is that to the include path, and of course I actually have SFML downloaded. I'm using g++ 12.1.0 and SFML 2.5.1 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Recommendation: Add the configuration file. I'm not a user of VS Code, but my understanding is the configuration of the runtime feedback (intellisense) is in a different file from the configuration for the compiler. You may have to specify the include paths in both files.

Comment: I believe VScode does this implicitly - there is a .json file attached with the configurations inside (c_cpp_properties.json), including the above include path. I'll look into it though. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if VS works with different targets but in my experience with other IDEs, this may be caused because you configured the include paths only for the release target and not for debug target